# Line bundles as a pull-back bundles via proper morphism with connected geometric fibres.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

A fundamental (and maybe very easy) question:

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper surjective morphism of algebraic varieties over complex numbers with connected geometric fibres. Let $\mathscr{L}\in\mathrm{Pic}(X)$ such that there exists an open covering $\{Y_i\}$ of $Y$ such that $\mathscr{L}|_{Y_i}\cong\mathscr{O}_{f^{-1}(Y_i)}$. Then there exists $\mathscr{M}\in\mathrm{Pic}(Y)$ such that $\mathscr{L}\cong f^*\mathscr{M}$.

Since we are over $\mathbb{C}$, then in this case $f_*\mathscr{O}_X=\mathscr{O}_Y$ by Stein-factorization. By the assumption, we may have $f_*\mathscr{L}\cong\mathscr{N}$ for some $\mathscr{N}\in\mathrm{Pic}(Y)$. So $f_*\mathscr{L}\cong f_* f^*\mathscr{N}$ by projection formula. But I don't know how to deduce the final result! Maybe we have $\mathscr{L}\cong f^*\mathscr{N}$ or some corrected line bundles. This seems like some non-flat but Zariski-local version of see-saw lemma.

Comment: Maybe try to look at the transition functions $\varphi_{ij} \in \mathcal O(f^{-1}(Y_i \cap Y_j))$. They should be constant along the fibers (which are proper connected schemes), hence come from $Y$.

Comment: @red_trumpet Thanks! This seems right. But I still want to know whether there is a global method or not.

Comment: You have a canonical map of line bundles $f^*f_* \mathcal L \to \mathcal L$. Can you show it is an isomorphism?